# c system call connect() hangs on client side (network programming)

Tags: c, network-programming, system-calls

I am learning sockets and I am following some sample code from textbook. I have two pc, one functions as a server and the other servers as a client. I try to make two pc communicate by sockets but client connect() call hangs. Because I just start learning so I have no idea what is going on.

I tried to search c connect() hangs but no luck. I got to know my server IP by ifcongif `inet 138.51.83.123`

server:

```
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <signal.h> 

#define SIZE sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)

void catcher(int sig);
int newsockfd;

int main(){
    int sockfd;
    char c;
    struct sockaddr_in server = {AF_INET, 7000, INADDR_ANY};
    static struct sigaction act;

    act.sa_handler = catcher;
    sigfillset(&(act.sa_mask));
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, NULL);

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("socket call failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, SIZE) == -1){
        perror("bind call failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(listen(sockfd, 5) == -1){
        perror("listen call failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(;;){
        if((newsockfd = accept(sockfd, NULL, NULL)) == -1){
            perror("accept call failed");
            continue;
        }

        if(fork() == 0){
            // keep reading if not EOF
            while(recv(newsockfd, &c, 1, 0) > 0){
                printf("***received: %c\n", c);
                c = toupper(c);
                send(newsockfd, &c, 1, 0);
            }
            close(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        // parent no need for newsockfd
        close(newsockfd);
    }
    return 0;
}

void catcher(int sig){
    close(newsockfd);
    exit(0);
}
```

client:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close

#define SIZE sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)

int main(){

    int sockfd;
    char c, rc;
    struct sockaddr_in server = {AF_INET, 7000};
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("138.51.83.71");
    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1){
        perror("socket call failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, SIZE) == -1){
        printf("here\n");
        perror("connect call failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("here\n"); // never got printed out


    for(;;){
        printf("Input a lowercase char\n");

        c = getchar();
        send(sockfd, &c, 1, 0);

        if(recv(sockfd, &rc, 1, 0) > 0) printf("receive: %c", rc);
        else{
            printf("server died\n");
            close(sockfd);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

in client, `printf("here\n"); // never got printed out` so that's why I guess client `connect()` hangs (I tried to put this printf before `connect()` and it was printed out). Can anyone help? Because I have no prior knowledge of network programming so I have no idea how to even debug.

Answer (score 1):

First try to ping the server's IP address from your client machine and see the results.If the ping was not successful that means there is some problem with your network connection. I ran your program with server's IP as 127.0.0.1(localhost) and it ran perfectly which suggests that there is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your client cannot see your server (using ping you will be able to detect this situation). If you are a Linux user, a easy way to debug this kind of program is using netcat. Netcat is a tool that let you, between other things, create clients or server through UDP or TCP. If you have your pieces of code in different machines, i would change (just for debug purposes) the IP to localhost, and I would launch:

**In server machine:**

```
netcat localhost 7000
hello world
```

It is a TCP server that you know that works propperly, so you will be able to detect if there is anything wrong in your server.

**In client machine**

```
netcat -l localhost 7000
```

Similar to the server machine, this command creates a a TCP server listening in localhost:7000.

It is possible that it does not solve your problem because it is seems to be a configuration issue, and it is difficult to give you some advice if we do not know what kind of machines and configuration settings you are working with. But I think netcat it is a powerful tool for this purpose.